# How can we define convexity in one dimension?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Definition of a convex set: A set $S\subset\mathbb R^n$ is said to be convex if for each $x_1, x_2\in S$ the line segment
$\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2$ for $\lambda\in (0,1)$ belongs to $S$.
This says that all points on the line connecting two points in the set are in
the set.

My question is: how can we define convexity in one dimension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$, the definition is **the same** and you can prove that it is equivalent to connexity, or simpler : 
$$A\subseteq\mathbb R\text{ is convex }\iff A\text{ is an interval}.$$

Comment: Hm... what does that look like geometrically?

Comment: @SimpleArt: Convexity says "the line segment between any two points is contained in the set". Since $\Bbb{R}$ is a line, a convex subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is itself a line segment, and therefore is an interval.

Answer (score 2):

The formulas in your question(as edited) work perfectly well in $\mathbb{R}$.
The collection of convex sets is the collection of intervals.

Comment: I mean i.e: points x1 and  x2 are  given at least from  two dimensional coordinates. I want this to reduce in just one dimension coordinate and to see how the equation takes form?

Comment: Your formula works for ${\mathbb{R}}^{n}$. Set $n = 1$.